# Encode image and change color in SDL2 and C ++

Tags: c++, colors, sdl-2, palette, sdl-image

Is there a method or function that: when loading a texture, it is coded to apply color changes?

[image]

How Sprite Works in NES

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it yourself. SDL wasn't done to works with NES texture format.
You'll need to load your texture array. Create a new surface with the right size. After that, you can fill the pixels with the colour corresponding to your colour palette. You could do it with a custom SDL_Palette, but this isn't a good practice.

> An SDL_Palette should never need to be created manually. It is automatically created when SDL allocates an SDL_PixelFormat for a surface. The colors values of an SDL_Surface's palette can be set with SDL_SetPaletteColors().
> [SDL_Palette Wiki Page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Palette)